# Can't compile linux kernel 5.10 with BTF type info enabled

Tags: linux-kernel, ebpf, bpf, libbpf

I am want to compile linux 5.10.162 with `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF=y`, the end goal being to enable [bpf CO-RE](https://nakryiko.com/posts/bpf-portability-and-co-re/). However, the build is failing with:

```
+ ./tools/bpf/resolve_btfids/resolve_btfids vmlinux
FAILED unresolved symbol udp_sock
```

I first thought it was something similar to [this issue](https://www.spinics.net/lists/kernel/msg3783348.html), but after moving to a newer gcc, the issue persists.

Relevant packages:

- gcc 11.1.0 (also tested with 10.2)
- dwarves 1.24 (also tested with 1.22)

Bear in mind don't have much experience compiling linux. Let me know if the `config` will be of use.

Comment: What architecture are you building for? How did you configure the kernel before starting the build? And also how did you enable `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO_BTF=y` specifically? I.E. which commands did you use?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I am targeting x86_64. I added the option directly in the config file (not through menuconfig) next to the linux.spec file. That said, I should’ve mentioned I am building a full distro all together (hence the spec file)

Comment: "*I added the option directly in the config file (not through menuconfig)*" -- So you ignored the warning (in the **.config** file) not to edit it? You need to use the **menuconfig** method to ensure that all *dependencies* are satisfied, as well as all *auto-selections* are performed.

Comment: Exactly what @sawdust said, you should not directly edit the `.config` file like that. Use one of the various `*config` targets to do that, like for example `menuconfig`.

Comment: see https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/DEBUG_INFO_BTF.html

Comment: Note that you don't necessarily need BTF for bpf CO-RE. Indeed, it's easier if you have it but, if you don't, you can directly get the `vmlinux.h` corresponding to your target's environment (e.g., with BTFGen).

Comment: @sawdust I tried adding the option through the menuconfig - same result. Any other advice?

Comment: Did you try a clean build? I.E. `make distclean`, `make my_board_defconfig`. `make menuconfig`, ... , and finally `make`.